# Datetime Behavior Pandas 1.5.3 versus 2.0.0

Tags: pandas, datetime

I observed the following:

Pandas 2.0.1:

```
pd.to_datetime('2023-02-01',dayfirst=True)
Timestamp('2023-01-02 00:00:00')
```

Pandas 1.5.3:

```
pd.to_datetime('2023-02-01',dayfirst=True)
Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00')
```

After reading the release note, I am still not clear why the behavior is different.